# Try to connect to aws ec2 Hbase using java hbase client

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, hbase

when I try to use java hbase client to create a table on my aws hbase
, it gives me exceptions:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=36, exceptions:

Sun Dec 13 08:26:29 EST 2015, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=69130: row 'wujintao,,00000000000000' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=Slave1,60020,1449708947932, seqNum=0
```

And my java code is like this:

```
public static Configuration configuration; 
static { 
    configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create(); 
    configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181"); 
    configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","ec2-52-2-133-43.compute-1.amazonaws.com,ec2-52-70-140-152.compute-1.amazonaws.com,ec2-52-70-195-91.compute-1.amazonaws.com"); 
//  configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181"); 

    configuration.set("hbase.master", "*ec2-52-2-133-43.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000"); 
}
```

does it means it has connected to the master but failed on the slaves? why fail?

Answer (score 0):

Does `hostname=Slave1,60020` defined in /etc/hosts file or Slave1 hostname is accessible from your client machine and master ? 
Hbase and others works with hostnames, even if you attemp to connect with ip, it will return hostname and try to use in it next call.